# Fragment Save State

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've read a lot about save states and fragments, but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have a fragment that is *loaded when the user signs in*. The user can then choose from a variety of categories, which will replace the current fragment with a new one. In this new fragment, the user can click items in a `GridView` which will cause a check to appear.

When I press the back button, how would I go about saving the clicked items? *`onSavedInstanceState` is never called*, and it seems like my fragment is being created all over again when I try to navigate back.

Some code:

**When the user first enters the app**

```
//  creates the home fragment
Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, homeFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**When the user clicks on a category**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("subCategory", subCategory);

Fragment ingredientsFragment = new IngredientsFragment();
ingredientsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, ingredientsFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you move From HomeFragment To IngredientsFragment you are replacing 1 fragment by another (HomeFragment By IngredientsFragment) so when you press back from IngredientsFragment then It will remove IngredientsFragment from stack also and HomeFragment is already removed and this is expected behavior.

What you can do is When you invoke IngredientsFragment Fragment then "add" it not replace and when user press back then remove IngredientsFragment from stack.

Comment: Do I need to override onBackPressed for this or can I just replace replace() with add() and keep everything else the same?

Comment: just replace replace() with add() and keep

Comment: The state of the IngredientsFragment, where some of the gridview items are checked, is not saved when I return to that same category